# Is there a way to get profession list from dbpedia with sparql?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Is there a way to retrieve all profession/Occupation (in frensh) from dbpedia ?
I try it with this code but it does not work :

```
SELECT distinct ?profession WHERE {
?profession rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Profession>.
}
```

---> 0 results returned. ...
I tried also this code :

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

SELECT ?profession 
WHERE {
?x a dbo:PersonFunction.
?x dbo:otherOccupation ?profession
}
```

but get 0 results returned.
What's missing?

Comment: "i have an error in output" - perhaps if you show the actual error, someone can help

Comment: Excuse me , it returned 0 results also not an error  : SPARQL results: [no results]

Comment: this isn't modelled that good in DBpedia - the closest you could get is maybe `select distinct ?t {
?s a dbo:PersonFunction ;
dbo:title ?t
}
order by ?t`

Comment: or `select distinct ?o {
?s dbo:occupation ?o .
}`

Comment: Okey thank you but if we want just a personfunction in frensh not english

Comment: I do not understand. If you want it in French, you should just query French Dbpedia: http://fr.dbpedia.org/sparql